# Is LDAP a protocol that imposes restrictions on underlying data structure?

Tags: ldap, protocols, graph-theory, network-protocols, set-theory

My understanding of LDAP is as follows:

1. LDAP is a protocol.
2. OpenLDAP, an implementation of LDAP, uses BDB as its default datastore. But, one of any number of datastores can be used by OpenLDAP.
3. There are other implementations of LDAP, as well. They each have their own default datastore and may or may not support swapping that store out for an other.
4. So, it is important to distinguish LDAP from the datastore an LDAP implementation uses.
5. Furthermore, the D in LDAP stands for Directory. But, a directory can be thought of more generally as a graph--specifically, a tree with one root, lots of branches, and no circular loops in the branches.
6. LDAP can used to manage a collection of trees, but it can not be used to manage a collection of direct acyclic graphs--or even more broadly, graphs with cycles in them.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

> LDAP is a protocol.

It *was* originally a protocol to communicate with X.500 directories, but it has grown into a directory specification of its own.

> OpenLDAP, an implementation of LDAP, uses BDB as its default datastore.

Used. The default in current versions is HDB.

> But, one of any number of datastores can be used by OpenLDAP.

Correct.

> There are other implementations of LDAP, as well. They each have their own default datastore and may or may not support swapping that store out for an other.

Correct.

> So, it is important to distinguish LDAP from the datastore an LDAP implementation uses.

Correct.

> Furthermore, the D in LDAP stands for Directory. But, a directory can be thought of more generally as a graph--specifically, a tree with one root, lots of branches, and no circular loops in the branches.

True.

> LDAP can used to manage a collection of trees, but it can not be used to manage a collection of direct acyclic graphs--or even more broadly, graphs with cycles in them.

False. This happens all the time, via the attribute mechanism. In my own system user is a member of groups which in turn are members of other groups and/or roles. There's a semantic reason why this wouldn't become cyclic, but there is no technical reason.